# C# - Rewriting URL with a form

Tags: c#, forms, url

I'm begining coding in C# with ASP.NET, I've a MVC project and I'm trying to rewrite the URL with a form.

I want the URL to call an action with 3 parameters, to adding these parameters as a row in a DB.

I thought to do a form with TextBoxes and Button in a .aspx file and creating a "onClick" method to change the URL.

Like this :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<script language="C#" runat="server">

        public void Ajouter(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                ///
        }

 </script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AjouterForm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ajouter un produit</h1>
    <div>
        <form id="form1" runat="server"  defaultbutton="bouton1" method="get">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox placeholder="Date" runat="server" ID="idForm"/></br>    
    <asp:TextBox placeholder="Name" runat="server" ID="nameForm"/></br>
    <asp:TextBox placeholder="User" runat="server" ID="userForm"/></br>

    <asp:Button runat="server" text="Envoyer" ID="bouton1" onClick="Ajouter"/>

...
```

I've done some research but unsuccessfully. If someone have a solution it would be awesome

Comment: Is there a reason that your using webforms in an MVC project? Not that theres a rule against it but you can accomplish this in MVC without switching to webforms. Just a thought. Also, Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the HowTo,
I'm developping a web app based on MVC configuration, did i say something wrong ? 
(I'm going to edit the main paragraph to put more precisions)

Comment: No, you didn't say anything wrong, I just like to share that link to anyone that's new to the site.

Comment: _"`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>"`"_ comes from a _really_ old tutorial. Try another one, start at http://www.asp.net/mvc.

Comment: Generally you don't mix webforms and MVC, you can easily create a form in MVC without using webforms. Also, to add to what CodeCaster said, when going through tutorials always watch the date, technologies change. I generally won't read a tutorial written before 2012.

Comment: here's a better walkthrough: http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/understanding-url-rewriting-and-url-attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-mvc5-with-examples

Comment: I change it with the line generated at a file.aspx creation.
But the problem is the Onclick function it's not the form, isn't it ?
So did you know how to do it..? There's no good tutorials about it

Comment: C# is one of the top 5 most popular languages, there are plenty of tutorials online. I shared one with you above. I really think you should start from scratch with another tutorial. When all else fails: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.140).aspx